# October CMS Rainlab Blog plugin get current category name?

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

I am trying to make a blog on October CMS using the Rainlab Blog plugin, and on my category page I would like to put the name of the current category as the title. I can't figure out anywhere how to do this, there is nothing in the docs about getting the current category, and Google can't find it for me either.

Answer (score 4):

Simply using {{ category.name }} in your category template should work.

If you don't have a custom category template (and are using the default one from the plugin) then you'll need to add one to your theme. Mine looks like this:

```
    title = "Blog Category"
    url = "/blog/category/:slug/:page?"
    layout = "default"

    [blogPosts]
    categoryFilter = "{{ :slug }}"

    ==
    function onEnd()
    {
        // Optional - set the page title to the category name
        if ($this->category)
            $this->page->title = $this->category->name;
    }
    ==

    <div class="container blog-category">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">

                        {% if not category %}
                            <h1>Category not found</h1>
                        {% else %}
                            <h1>{{ category.name }}</h1>

                    {% for post in posts %}

                    {% partial "blog/list-single" post=post %}

                    {% else %}

                        <div class="no-data">{{ noPostsMessage }}</div>

                    {% endfor %}

                        {% endif %}

                    </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi Staple how would implement this if you were using utopigs pluging as I am unable to parse the category name or title I just get blog catergory without the the catergory name